# How to disable keyboard popup?

Tags: android, android-keypad

The keyboard pops up wherever there's an EditText item. I wan't to disable this popup from occurring automatically and only want the keyboard to appear when the user manually sets focus on the EditText field. 
I have added the following in my Manifest file but it doesn't appear to work:

```
<activity android:name=".AccountActivity" android:label="yourtime" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"></activity>
```

Comment: please add this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

Comment: do I need to add this to every view using EditText?

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba I guess you already figured, but if someone did not - No, not every EditText (or every View in general) just put it in **onCreate** method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already wrote in the comment use the getWindow() method of your host-activity to set the `SOFT_INPUT_STATE_AL‌​WAYS_HIDDEN` flag. There is no need to invoke anything on an EditText when you want to disable the up-popping keyboard generally in this specific activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set this in the manifest file. For each activity, add the following attribute.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```